# Capistrano apt-get or gem?

Tags: installation, capistrano

I want to start work with capistrano and want to install it on my server. I have Ubuntu 14.04. Many manuals on the web say that it's better to use gem. But 'aptitude search capistrano' has result too. What the difference? What the apt package for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `sudo apt-cache showpkg capistrano` it shows that Ubuntu 14.04 would install capistrano version 2.12. The current version of capistrano is version 3.

If you're fine with version 2 and you want to use plain capistrano you're good to go.

But if you for instance want to deploy Rails applications then you would need to install *capistrano-rails* and if you are using RVM or rbenv then you want to install the respective capistrano gems. In these cases I would rather go with the gems.